# How do I assert that observe takes a queue that I can add As to, without necessarily caring what else the queue could hold?

Tags: python, types

I have an asyncio.Queue with items of either A or B type. I therefore typed my class like this:

```
class Observer:
   def __init__(self):
       self.queue: Queue[A|B] = asyncio.Queue()
```

There is another method that takes the queue and calls queue.put with an A item. I'd like to type hint like this, but it fails:

```
def observe(queue: Queue[A]):
    ... # does stuff
    item = A(...)
    queue.put(item)
```

Now, Queue[A] is incompatible with Queue[A|B], obviously. How can I type hint the queue parameter such that it takes any Queue that accepts A items, regardless of other types it also accepts?

For what is worth, I already tried Protocols like this. And it fails saying A is incompatible with A|B.

```
class CanPutA(Protocol):
    async def put(self, item: A):
        ...
```

Comment: What does the argument to `observe` have to do with the `queue` attribute? `Queue[A]` is not necessarily incompatible: if all you are doing is adding `A`s to `queue`, then a `Queue[A|B]` value is sufficient. (The problem comes if you try to *read* from `observe`'s argument, since you could get a `B`.)

Comment: Are you *passing* some `Observer`'s `queue` as the argument to `observe`?

Comment: Can a given observer hold items of either type, or does a single observer either have all `A`s` or all `B`s? You might want `Observer` to be a generic class instead, like `class Observer(Generic[T]): queue: Queue[T]`. Then, you could *only* pass the `queue` attribute of an `Observer[A]` value to `observer`.

Comment: @chepner eventually, the class will call `observe(self.queue)`. and the point is it will hold items of type A or B at the same time.

Comment: Ok, so the question is definitely "How do I assert that `observe` takes a queue that I can *add* `A`s to, without necessarily caring what else the queue could hold?" Nothing comes to mind at the moment, but it's an interesting question.

Comment: (I mean, you could always write `observe(cast(Queue[A], self.queue))`, but that's obviously less than ideal.)

Comment: changed the title to that. it's a more specific question, even though the answer can be generalized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CanPutA` can work if you make it generic *and* contravariant, but see below.

```
T = TypeVar('T', contravariant=True)

class CanPut(Protocol[T]):
    async def put(self, item: T):
        ...


 def observe(queue: CanPut[A]):
     item = A(...)
     queue.put(A)
```

Contravariance allows `Queue[A|B]` as an argument, because `Queue[A]` is a subclass of `Queue[A|B]`. (Ordinarily, generics are *invariant*, which means your `CanPutA` only accepted containers of `A` exactly, not sub- or superclasses of `A`.)

(In fact, if you didn't know about contravariance and just tried the generic protocol, `mypy` will tell you here that you are using an invariant type variable where a contravariant one is expected.

It's a quirk of `mypy` that *containers* are co-, contra-, or invariant, but you make that declaration on the type variables used to define them instead of on the generic itself.)

---

There is a caveat: `observe` no longer is restricted to `Queue`s, but *any* class with an appropriate `put` method. That's probably OK. What `mypy` (at least) lacks is support for *intersection* types, which would allow you to say that `queue` must be both a `Queue` of some kind *and* something that supports `CanPut[A]`.

```
 # Hypothetical
 def observe(queue: Intersection[Queue, CanPut[A]]):
     ...
```

Intersection types are on the radar of the `mypy` developers, but a combination of the perceived importance and estimated amount of work to implement correctly has prevented it from being supported to date.